# vuelidate doesn't show the message on conditional statement

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I'm using vuelidate for the validation of my app (`vue3`), and for this I have an email field. Obviously, the email field has to have both email and required validations. I'm trying to show a message based on the type of the validation but when I do that using the v-if v-else, it doesn't look to work. Nothing happens and no message is shown.
Here is my code

(`HTML`):

```
    <label for="email1" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="email" :class="'form-control'" name="email1" id="email1" 
    placeholder="Entrer l'email" required v-model="email">  
    <div class="error" v-if="!$v.email.required">Field is required</div>
   <div class="error" v-if="!$v.email.email">Name must have at least email letters.</div>
```

(`JS`)

```
  data(){
    return{
        $v : useVuelidate(),
        email:'',
    }
},
   validations() {
    return{
        email : {required,email},

   }
   },
```

Comment: You're trying to mix new vuelidate version with options api. This won't work. The name useVuelidate implies that it's supposed to be used with composition api.

Answer (score 0):

That might work

```js
export default {
  setup () {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() }
  },
```